# downloading PPTX created by python-pptx in a flask app

Tags: python, flask, python-pptx

I am using Python-pptx in a web app, that programmatically creates a powerpoint and then allows the user to download at the end.  People can upload images, etc, and it inserts it into the powerpoint for them.

Works great, however currently I am saving the PowerPoint to the "static" folder and then creating a download link with its file path.

Ideally, I want the file to never be saved to the server. This is to prevent privacy issues regarding sensitive information. It would also be great if people didn’t have to log in.  Just a simple, secure way to make powerpoints.

I tried to get send_file to work to no avail. I think it is the solution though.

Here’s what I tried:

```
prs = Presentation()
file_name = 'static/' + file_name + '.pptx'

root_dir = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
path = os.path.join(root_dir, 'project', 'static', 'test.pptx')


return send_file(prs, as_attachment=True)

# also tried:

# return send_file(path, mimetype='applicationvnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation', as_attachment=True)

# which loads the page, but doesn’t trigger a download,just loads a blank page.
# plus, it is referencing a file path which means the file was saved on the server
```

Would appreciate any help! It's my first flask app!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** In Python 3 you would use:

```py
import io

outfile = io.BytesIO()
prs.save(outfile)
```

---

You can save the presentation to an "in-memory" file, something roughly like this:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

out_file = StringIO()
prs.save(out_file)
```

`python-pptx` likes memory streams like StringIO just fine and will happily write the file to it just like it was a disk file. Then you can send the file for download just like it was an open disk file handle.

There's a little bit more in the documentation here: http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/presentations.html#opening-a-file-like-presentation

Comment: Only on the internet will you get a response from the guy who created it :) Thank you for your reply! (And awesome awesome library!)

I'm afraid I'm still a bit stuck.  What would I be sending if that file is in memory? 

My send file now looks like:
 return send_file(out_file, mimetype='applicationvnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation', as_attachment=True)

Comment: Well, I think that's a Flask question, but what I would try is using the StringIO object as out_file and see if that works. Typically it would. I notice in the send_file() documentation it allows "filename or fp" for the first parameter: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.send_file. If that doesn't work you'd just search around on sending a StringIO object with send_file() and I'm sure you'll come across it :)

Comment: awesome, thank you for your help! I'll comment if I find the answer.  :)

Comment: return send_file(out_file,
                  attachment_filename="testing.pptx",
                  as_attachment=True)

that was my send_file, I added a target="_blank" to the form I submit, and that is what made it finally download.  (before it was loading a blank page, with no download, and now it opens the new page and downloads).  Works great! Can't thank you enough :)

Comment: Hey - I don't know if I should comment on this one or create a new post but following the above answer, I keep getting the error `string argument expected, got 'bytes'`, any thoughts on how to tackle this?